# How to align legend dynamically on top-center of the chart in c3.js?

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I want to put the same legend top center of the chart. Legend items will be dynamic, likes sometimes 2,5 or 9, etc.
So, it should take space dynamically like how it is acting on the bottom.
[image]

I tried with inset functionality but it seems this is not looking better like the bottom one.

[image]

and there are few more complexity like I want it like a flat, so now if I define step size 3 then maybe, for now, it looks good for 9 items. but when there will be 2 items, it will show as a list!!

Answer (score 0):

Although I solved that problem through the following solution:

```js
 // get parent elements
        let parentEle = d3.selectAll("#chartID svg");
        let childrenEle = parentEle
          //Convert selection to selection representing the children
          .selectAll(function () { return this.childNodes; })
          .filter('g');
        // putting legends position on TOP 
        d3.select(childrenEle._groups[0][2]).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 5)');
```

- you have to keep eye on chart width - height and according to this, you may have to control padding in TOP for the chart.
- might be this is not a good solution but it works fine for me :D